# Caption fontsize in a listing using minted

Tags: captions, ieeetran, minted

With `listing` and `minted` and a `pycon` lexer to emulate an IPython console, I'd like to change the caption font size to be `\footnotesize`. Unfortunately, my code below does not change the fontsize of the caption "heading" i.e. the fontsize of "Listing 1:" does not change.

I can't use the caption package because of the IEEEtran document class.

```
\documentclass[journal,12pt,onecolumn,draftclsnofoot,]{ieee_template/IEEEtran/IEEEtran}
\usepackage{listing}    
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\usepackage{minted}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\newminted{pycon}{bgcolor=bg, linenos=true, tabsize=4}

\begin{document}

    \begin{listing}[]% * for across both columns
        \begin{minted}[mathescape, frame=lines, framesep=2mm, fontsize=\footnotesize]{pycon} 
        In [1]: %run listing_minted_demo.py
        Hello World!
        x = 3 + 2 
        \end{minted}
    \caption[]{\footnotesize{Example caption. I'd like the caption AND the label Listing 1 to be footnotesize.}}
    %\label{mwe}
    \end{listing}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output (see "Listing 1" is typeset in a larger font):
[image]

Comment: Hey and welcome to tex.sx. Your MWE is not compiling well (e.g. you have `\usepackage`s before the `\documentclass`). Could you fix this? This will make it easier for others to help you. And maybe also specify what exactly you're asking, as this is not clear from your post.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `listing` to use the same setup for the caption as `figure`.

Looking in the `listing` package one finds the way:

```latex
\documentclass[journal,12pt,onecolumn,draftclsnofoot]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{listing}    
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\usepackage{minted}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\newminted{pycon}{bgcolor=bg, linenos=true, tabsize=4}

% let `listing` use the same caption format as figure
\makeatletter
\let\@float@c@listing\@caption
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[htp]% * for across both columns
\begin{minted}[mathescape, frame=lines, framesep=2mm, fontsize=\footnotesize]{pycon} 
In [1]: %run listing_minted_demo.py
Hello World!
x = 3 + 2 
\end{minted}
\caption{Example caption. I'd like the caption AND the label Listing 1 to be footnotesize.}
\label{mwe}
\end{listing}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{3cm}\rule{3cm}{0pt}}
\caption{Example caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @problemofficer Maybe you have some reason; but downvoting before asking is rude, on this site.

Answer (score 0):

**Non-recommended way for this specific `documentclass` because it handles captions its own way and this way breaks this functionality.**

A possible solution since you don't really share what you really expect as output:

```
\documentclass[journal,12pt,onecolumn,draftclsnofoot,]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{listing}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font={normalsize}, textfont={sf}, labelfont={bf,sf}}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\newminted{pycon}{bgcolor=bg, linenos=true, tabsize=4}

\begin{document}

    \begin{listing}[]% * for across both columns
        \begin{minted}[mathescape, frame=lines, framesep=2mm, fontsize=\footnotesize]{pycon} 
        In [1]: %run listing_minted_demo.py
        Hello World!
        x = 3 + 2 
        \end{minted}
        \captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}
    \caption[]{\footnotesize Example caption. I'd like the caption AND the label Listing 1 to be footnotesize.}
    %\label{mwe}
    \end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `normalsize` and not `footnotesize` as the OP seems to want a footnotesize caption (See the contents of the caption command: 'I'd like the caption AND the label Listing 1 to be footnotesize.' ?

Comment: @leandriis I did it for the specific caption... may be (s)he don't want this option to be global across the document and the post doesn't share enough details. This way I give more possible choices to every usage because I used `\captionsetup` globally but locally too.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have overlooked the local definition of the caption's font.  Apart from that, combining the `caption` package and `IEEEtran` documentclass seems to be discuraged in the documentation ('[...]  caption.sty, which, in its default con-figuration,  will  overrride  IEEEtran’s  handling  of  captions — resulting  in  non-IEEE  style  main  captions' (see page 10)) and also results in a corresponding warning.

Comment: @leandriis thanks... I forgot that! You are right... I will add a non-suggested comment on the top of my answer (and a non-suggested documentclass in this comment :P )

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. When I first posted, my explanatory text before the Latex was omitted. Hopefully, what I have added helps.